# Android media player set video scaling mode

Tags: android, video, scale, stretch

I use:

```
 mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(android.media.MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
```

but it is not working i want to fit video to screen.

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 6):

`VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT` is the value by default, so calling to

```
mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(android.media.MediaPlayer
                                .VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
```

will make no difference.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#setVideoScalingMode(int)

> The default is "scale to fit".

As example, grab the following MediaCodec based player:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

and experiment by setting `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT` or `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING`in MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.java

---

Adding a bit more.

What you are trying to accomplish can be done the following way:

Implement the onMeasure on your SurfaceView.

Get the video size.

Call to setMeasuredDimension with different values depending if you want to Stretch, Fit or Crop your video:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = getDefaultSize(videoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(videoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Do not change w & h for screen fill
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        // Experiment by changing width & height compared to the video size
        // for different results
    }
```

Comment: FYI, `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING` is not working right now. It's a known issue: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1428

Comment: If you wish, and use it in normal Activity/Fragment, I've shown how to scale videos on ExoPlayer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231575/878126