# In ExoPlayer, how exactly to use SimpleExoPlayer.setVideoScalingMode to be like in ImageView center-crop?

Tags: android, scale, exoplayer2.x

### Background

I'm trying to have a video shown in center-crop manner (like on ImageView).

I also hope I can find how to scale in other ways, as done on [**this library**](https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableVideoView).

### The problem

I use this for this purpose :

```
    player!!.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
```

But for some reason it doesn't do center-cropping.

### What I've tried

Looking at the docs, I see this:

"Note that the scaling mode only applies if a MediaCodec-based video Renderer is enabled and if the output surface is owned by a SurfaceView."

So I tried to set this in the XML file:

```
     app:surface_type="surface_view"
```

but it also didn't help. I don't see it available in code, either.

I tried to search for anything with "renderer" or "codec" for this class, but none exist.

Here's the code I use (based on this: https://github.com/yusufcakmak/ExoPlayerSample ) :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val VIDEO_URL = "https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"
    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    private var window: Timeline.Window? = null
    private var mediaDataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory? = null
    private var trackSelector: DefaultTrackSelector? = null
    private var shouldAutoPlay: Boolean = false
    private var bandwidthMeter: BandwidthMeter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        shouldAutoPlay = true
        bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        mediaDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), bandwidthMeter as TransferListener<in DataSource>)
        window = Timeline.Window()
    }

    private fun initializePlayer() {
        if (player != null)
            return
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus()
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector)
        simpleExoPlayerView.player = player
        player!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        player!!.playWhenReady = shouldAutoPlay
        player!!.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
        val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory()
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(VIDEO_URL), mediaDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null)
        player!!.prepare(mediaSource)
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            shouldAutoPlay = player!!.getPlayWhenReady()
            player!!.release()
            player = null
            trackSelector = null
        }
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null) {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            releasePlayer()
        }
    }

    public override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            releasePlayer()
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/simpleExoPlayerView" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true" app:surface_type="surface_view"/>
```

**manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**gradle file**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2'
```

### The questions

1. What's wrong in what I did?
2. What is exactly the first requirement?
3. I think this version of the SDK is a bit old. How should I update it ? Maybe it's a bug and it got fixed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I got it. Had to update the SDK and for some reason use support library instead of Android-X version of it.

There are some scaling types available, called "ResizeMode" ([**here**](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/index.html?com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.ResizeMode.html)) :

- zoom = same as center-crop
- fit = same as fit-center
- fill = same as fit-xy (stretching, without keeping aspect ratio)

Here's the code:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, DefaultTrackSelector())
        playerView.player = player
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, getUserAgent(this))
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mkv"))
        player!!.prepare(mediaSource)
        playerView.useController=false
        player!!.playWhenReady = true
        player!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        playerView.player = null
        player!!.release()
        player = null
    }

    fun getUserAgent(context: Context): String {
        val packageName = context.packageName
        val info = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
        val appName = info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.packageManager).toString()
        val versionName = info.versionName
        return "$appName/$versionName (Linux;Android ${Build.VERSION.RELEASE}) ${ExoPlayerLibraryInfo.VERSION_SLASHY}"
    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**layout**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--zoom=center-crop fit=center-inside fill-stretch-->

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:resize_mode="zoom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.1'
}
```